# Getting an element of a html file from an external js file

Tags: javascript, html

I would like help with this problem, i have a file named, index.html, and a file named javascript.js. When i do document.getElementById("canvas"), and then try to change something like the width of the canvas, it gives me a null exception.

Html file

```
<html>
    <body>
        <canvas> </canvas>
        <script src="javascript.js"></script>
        <script>getCanvas.start();</script>
    </body>
</html>
```

JavaScript file

```
var canvas;
function getCanvas() {
    canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
    canvas.width = 500;
}
```

At line 4, google chrome throws me the following error on the console. Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set the property 'width' of null.

A huge thanks to anybody who helps.

Answer (score 1):

You have to specify `id` to canvas element

```
<canvas id="canvas"> </canvas>
```

Comment: Thank you soo much, that was a rookie mistake.

Answer (score 0):

`document.getElementById("canvas");` will get you the element which has the id of 'canvas'. Your canvas element does not have the id 'canvas'.

**Solution**:

```
<canvas id="canvas"> </canvas>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementById("canvas");
```

This it self say get Element By **ID** and you didn't give set id.

Try This in your HTML:-

```
<canvas id="canvas"> </canvas>
```

Answer (score 0):

Without changing your html, you can use it as such:

```
document.body.getElementsByTagName('canvas');
```